# Bulletsharp DiscreteDynamicsWorld RemoveRigidBody behaves strangely

Tags: c#, bulletphysics

I am adding and removing RigidBodies to an DiscreteDynamicsWorld.
If I just add one body at a time and remove it again it works like expected.

If I add more bodies (3-5) at once and remove some of them again, it's sometimes removing the wrong items.

It took me about a day to achieve the desired result but I do not understand why it is not working the other way.

Code:

```
private ConcurrentBag<RigidBody> _toRemove = new ConcurrentBag<RigidBody>();

while (!_toRemove.IsEmpty)
{
    RigidBody body;
    if (_toRemove.TryTake(out body))
    {    
        //Not working
        InternWorld.RemoveRigidBody(body);

        //also not working
        InternWorld.CollisionObjectArray.Remove(body);

        //working
        for (int i = 0; i < InternWorld.CollisionObjectArray.Count; i++)
        {                        
            if(body == InternWorld.CollisionObjectArray[i])
            {
                InternWorld.CollisionObjectArray.RemoveAt(i);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone explain why the first two ways are not working? Is this a bug in bullet/bulletsharp or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I can replicate this, working on it:)
https://github.com/AndresTraks/BulletSharp/issues/39

Comment: Should be fixed now, it was a typo in BulletSharp. Sorry!

Comment: I am glad I could help to find the problem :) Thanks for your work.